# Photo Competition 2021-10-04: Festivals

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Festivals

Capture a photo of a scene that demonstrates a "*festival celebration*", or something which highlights what the festival is about, etc. The subject may be a person or a group of people, or even an inanimate object, so long as the key concept of festive season is the central focus of the photograph.

Festival doesn't have to be *necessarily* something "*official*" like *Christmas*. People may have local customs and hence accordingly local festivals too.

So, any sort of festival pictures are welcomed.

This theme was suggested by [Aquarius_Girl](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/5205/aquarius-girl).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/126354/photo-competition-2021-10-04-festivals?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on October 18, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Renaissance Festival near Charlotte NC. My first year attending. This photo captures a lot of the feel of the festival - hot, dusty, magical- with the backlight of the sun really bringing out some of the latent energy while the festivalgoers moved from experience to experience.

Taken with an iPhone 6 in 2016. f2.2 at 1/3049 sec at ISO 32 (according to the meta-data).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

### [Your Favorite Enemies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Your_Favorite_Enemies) at Midi Festival

It was a great performance with a crazy crowd, there were numerous [diving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stage_diving) and [crowd surfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowd_surfing) from the audience but what's shown is the vocal surfing while recording with a camcorder at the end of the performance.

05/08/2011, Central Park, Shanghai

50D, 50mm, f/3.2, ISO 100, 1/1250

[image: Your Favorite Enemies at Midi Festival]

Answer (score 5):

## Please can **I** play?

[image: Can I join?]

Spotted at a village festival celebration in Arriondas, Spain

Ss:1/125
F:5.6
Iso:250
42mm

Answer (score 4):

**stairways to heaven**

[image]

Taken during the Deepavali festival in Batu Cave (Malaysia, Kuala Lumpur)

Sony a6000,35mm,f/1.8, 1/2000 sec.

Answer (score 3):

**Festival Snack**

[image: 9th Avenue International Food Festival, 2019]

A couple at the 9th Avenue International Food Festival in Hell’s Kitchen, Manhattan sampling a tasty bite in 2019.  The annual festival hasn’t been on the last two years due to the coronavirus.

Canon EOS 6D, 85mm, f/2, 1/2500 second, ISO 100

Answer (score 2):

Saxorior ends its gig at Fimbul Festival 2021. After the long dry spell of festivals and concerts, having a small but awesome festival was an absolute blast for everyone involved. Located in the ruins of a local castle, which traditionally held a similar festival earlier in the year.

15th september, Canon R6, Tamron 70-200@70mm, F2.8, 1/200s, ISO5000.

[image: Saxorior - Fimbul Festival 2021]

Answer (score 1):

**Fairbanks, Alaska: Annual Red Green Regatta That Wasn't**
[image]
20 July 2014
D7000, Nikkor 18-140, f/7.1, 1/250s, ISO 400

Annual Red Green Regatta float down the Chena river in Fairbanks, Alaska that didn't happen due to high water (boats couldn't get under the bridges + swift water). Instead, the creations were on display and judged in a parking lot. The 30+ entries are all bespoke and construction inspiration is from the "Red Green Show" (Canadian comedy at its best). Durability of the boats is also along the line of the Red Green Show creations, i.e., dubious. Duct tape is the main construction medium for the boats and many costumes. The upper image is a boat framed with branches & dog pees on passersby. Unfortunately the 19th, and last, regatta was held a year later.

Answer (score 1):

**The Satyr, Fairy & Unicorn Festival**

OK, it's our own festival but we definitely enjoyed our photo session and pseudo-parade around the beautiful finger lakes in the fall.

10/14/2020 Naples, NY

Canon EOS T3
F/8, 1/200, ISO-100, 18mm
[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Talkeetna Live at Five

[image]

Every Friday from 5-7 in the summer, Talkeenta hosts a concert, with many people setting up lawn chairs and having a good time.

Talkeetna, Alaska, August 6th 2021

Nikon D500 with Nikkor 18-140

f/5, 1/2500, ISO 898