# Photo Competition 2021-10-18: Black and White, Metaphorically

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Black and White, Metaphorically

In this theme, black and white should be represented *conceptually*, not literally.

This theme was suggested by [mattdm](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1943).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/126354/photo-competition-2021-10-04-festivals?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on November 1, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Comment: So is the theme basically opposites?

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 Opposite, contrasting concepts, no-middle-ground, newsprint... these are all metaphorically black-and-white.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## "Darkness Sleeps"

[image]

### Specs

From a "Darkness and Light" series I shot in May 2019.

- Canon EOS R w/ RF24-105mm F4 L IS USM
- 74mm f/10 1/250s ISO 1250
- Portable strobe with 2x4' softbox.

Answer (score 6):

**Under Pressure**
[image]

Part of a series of photos pitting nature against machine.
Taken in September 2019 with a Sony A65. f/5.6 at 1/6 second using a 120 mm lens and a tripod.

Note - I used a found nest and fake eggs - no birds (or eggs) were harmed while taking this picture.

Comment: Great photo! Reminds me of the [liner notes](https://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/rush/images/albums/graceunderpressure-2-s.jpg) to Rush's _Grace Under Pressure_ album.

Answer (score 5):

### A Morning of Mourning

[image: A Morning of Mourning]

Twenty years later, the sun rises on a rose placed at the 9/11 Memorial in New York to honor and remember one of the brave heroes who gave his life to save others.

Nikon D700, Nikkor 105mm 1.8 Macro @ 1/320 sec. f/5.6 ISO 800
(Also literally Black and White)

Answer (score 4):

**Soft and hard**

[image]

Finland July 15, 2021

Canon EOS 6D, EF100mm f/2.8 Macro USM

100mm, f/4, 1/800s, ISO 800

Answer (score 1):

### Whose snack?

[image]

Alcatraz July 7th 2021

Nikon D500 with Sigma 150-600

ISO 200, f/5, 1/1600